# Contradicting Basic and Force definitions of types of Equilibrium

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, vectors, equilibrium

This question is neither a check my work question and nor a homework question, it is a conceptual doubt in a question I found and I have attached a solution just for reference to show how I drew my conclusions. All my previous posts containing this question have been closed due to some reason like this one or "lacks clarity" (please comment if you cannot understand my post and do not vote to close it, I will update the post ASAP because I am apparently at the risk of being banned from asking questions).

So I have read that a particle is in Stable Equilibrium when the potential energy is minimum, Unstable Equilibrium when the potential energy is maximum and Neutral Equilibrium when the potential energy is neither maximum or minimum. All of these definitions have the condition that net force on the particle = $0$ (or the particle is at equilibrium or $\frac {dU}{dr} = 0$.

Some extensions of these concepts or different definitions of Equilibrium are : "A particle is said to be in Stable Equilibrium when a slight displacement of the particle from equilibrium position makes it oscillate about that position (which means it returns back to the mean position) or that the forces acting on the particle are in the opposite direction to the displacement. The particle is in Unstable Equilibrium when a slight displacement of the particle from equilibrium position makes it go farther away from the position (which means it cannot come back to the mean position) or the forces acting on the particle are in the direction of displacement."

So the question that I have my doubt in is as follows :

"Two positive charges + q each are fixed at points (-a, 0) and (a, 0). A third charge + Q and mass m is placed at origin. What is the type of equilibrium when a charge Q is given a small displacement along the direction of the line x = y." The answer given is "no type of equilibrium"

Firstly I don't understand if the problem is stating whether the particle is constrained to move in the direction of the line x = y only (in which case the equilibrium is surely stable) or just the displacement is in the direction of the line x = y and that the particle is free to move after that (let us assume the latter case).

I know there has to be some type of equilibrium because the particle does have net force = $0$ at origin (or $\frac {dU}{dr} = 0$ at origin) (any equilibrium position has an equilibrium type associated with it).

Here is my working :

Let Charge Q is displaced to point (x,x) and x = A

[image]

$F_1$ (the force on charge Q due to charge q at (a,$0$) = $\frac {KQq}{((a-x)^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} ((x-a)\hat i + y\hat j)$

$F_2$ (the force on charge Q due to charge q at (-a,$0$) = $\frac {KQq}{((x+a)^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} ((x+a)\hat i + y\hat j)$

for small y we can neglect $y^2$ in comparison to $(a-x)^2$

$\therefore F_1 = \frac {KQq}{((a-x)^2)^{3/2}} ((x-a)\hat i + y\hat j) = \frac {KQq}{((a-x)^3)} ((x-a)\hat i + y\hat j)$

$\therefore F_2 = \frac {KQq}{((x+a)^2)^{3/2}} ((x+a)\hat i + y\hat j) = \frac {KQq}{((x+a)^3)} ((x+a)\hat i + y\hat j)$

Taking a common in the denominator we get

$F_1 = \frac {KQq}{a^3((1-\frac {x}{a})^3)} ((x-a)\hat i + y\hat j) = \frac {KQq}{a^3}{((1-\frac {x}{a})^{-3})} ((x-a)\hat i + y\hat j)$

$F_2 = \frac {KQq}{a^3((1-\frac {x}{a})^3)} ((x+a)\hat i + y\hat j) = \frac {KQq}{a^3}{((1+\frac {x}{a})^{-3})} ((x+a)\hat i + y\hat j)$

Using the binomial approximation $(1+x)^n = 1 + nx$ for $x<<1$ in $(1-\frac {x}{a})^{-3}$ to get $(1+3\frac{x}{a})$ and in $(1+\frac {x}{a})^{-3}$ to get $(1-3\frac{x}{a})$

So we get

$F_1 = \frac {KQq}{a^3}(1+3\frac{x}{a})((x-a)\hat i + y\hat j) = \frac {KQq}{a^3}((x-a+3\frac{x^2}{a}-3x)\hat i + (y+3\frac{xy}{a})\hat j)$

$F_2 = \frac {KQq}{a^3}(1-3\frac{x}{a})((x+a)\hat i + y\hat j) = \frac {KQq}{a^3}((x+a-3\frac{x^2}{a}-3x)\hat i + (y-3\frac{xy}{a})\hat j)$

Let F = $F_{net} = F_1  + F_2 = \frac {KQq}{a^3}((x-a+3\frac{x^2}{a}-3x)\hat i + (y+3\frac{xy}{a})\hat j) + \frac {KQq}{a^3}((x+a-3\frac{x^2}{a}-3x)\hat i + (y-3\frac{xy}{a})\hat j) = \frac {KQq}{a^3}(-4x\hat i + 2y\hat j)$

Let $F_x$ = component of F in x direction
Let $F_y$ = component of F in y direction

$F_x = \frac {-4KQqx}{a^3}$ and $F_y = \frac {2KQqy}{a^3}$

$F_x = ma_x = m\frac {d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac {-4KQqx}{a^3}$ and $F_y = ma_y = m\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac {2KQqy}{a^3}$

$\therefore \frac {d^2x}{dt^2} = -(\sqrt2w^2)x$ and $\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} = w^2y$

$\therefore x = Acos(\sqrt2wt)$ and $y = Ae^{wt}$ (because x,y are = A at time t = $0$)

If we go by the definition that the force is in or opposite to the direction of displacement, then we get that it does not come under any type of equilibrium (because the force comes out to be $\frac {2KQqx}{a^3}$(-2$\hat i$ + $\hat j$ for a small displacement of the particle from $(0,0)$ to (x,x). This is neither along nor opposite to the displacement from mean position.)

Now, if we go by the definition that the particle is in Unstable Equilibrium if it can not return to the mean position due to a small displacement then the Q charge is in Unstable Equilibrium. (for small displacement the (x,y) coordinates of the particle as a function of time are $(A cos (\sqrt 2wt), Ae^{wt})$ where $w = \sqrt \frac {2KQq}{ma^3}$). So the particle can never return to the mean position because the the y coordinate increases exponentially and when the small displacement assumption is not considered, the y coordinate still keeps increasing making it impossible for the particle to return (the force in y direction is in the direction of displacement in y direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good way of answering your question is to look at a potential diagram which will be three dimensional.

Using your symbols with the two $q=1$ fixed charges at positions $(-1,0)$ $(+1,0)$and setting the constant in Coulomb's law equal to one the potential at a position $(x,y)$ is $V= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+(1+x)^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+(1-x)^2}}$ and you can think of this as a plot of the potential energy, $U$, if the third charge $Q=+1$.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%5BU%3D1%2Fsqrt%28y%5E2%2B%281%2Bx%29%5E2%29%2B1%2Fsqrt%28y%5E2%2B%281-x%29%5E2%29%5D) can be used to do the plotting.

[image]

You can now see that if the third positive charge is placed anywhere other than position $(0,0)$ it will "roll down a hill" and be in a position of *unstable* equilibrium.
The exception at position $(0,0)$ is a *saddle point* where movement only along the $y=0$ line from position $(0,0)$ increases the potential energy and so the restoring force brings the positive charge back to position $(0,0)$ which along the direction is a position of *stable* (static) equilibrium.
However, any movement off the $y=0$ line will result the charge "rolling down the hill" which is a characteristic of *unstable* equilibrium.

So what happens if the third charge is negative?
The potential energy plot becomes negative as shown below using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%5BU%3D-1%2Fsqrt%28y%5E2%2B%281%2Bx%29%5E2%29-1%2Fsqrt%28y%5E2%2B%281-x%29%5E2%29%5D).

[image]

Again all positions except $(0,0)$ are unstable with a saddle point at position $(0,0)$ with motion only along the $x=0$ line showing a position of stable equilibrium at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I never thought of plotting the potential diagrams, thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the context, the question means that the charge can only move along the $x=y$ line. Thus in your calculation, you need to impose $x=y$ and project the force in the $i+j$ direction.

Alternatively, you can also calculate the energy on the line. Your method of calculating the force is equally valid but more computational since you need to calculate both components and then project which is a waste.

To study the stability, you just need to look at its asymptotics around $0$ to check whether it’s a local maximum/minimum or something else. The only advantage is that you don’t need to go as far in the asymptotic expansion.

For example, in your case (setting $a=1$, $\frac{qQ}{4\pi\epsilon_0}=1$):
$$
\begin{align}
U &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+x^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+x^2}} \\
&= 2+x^2
\end{align}
$$
This is consistent by setting $x=y$ and projecting your force in your final formula. So you have a stable equilibrium at the origin due to the local minimum.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For x=y I know we get stable equilibrium but how is "displaced along x=y" same as constrained to move along x=y?

Answer (score 1):

The charge Q is not in equilibrium anywhere along the x=y line except at the origin because it experiences an accelerating force away from the origin.

At the origin it is in stable equilibrium along the plus or minus x-axis due to it experiencing a restoring force towards the origin. It is in unstable equilibrium along the plus or minus y-axis where it experiences an an accelerating force away from the origin. See the electric field lines in the diagram below.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I get it, thank you